# expo React-native data not rendering but logs in console

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I was fetching data from API it's working fine, using react-native with expo I'm using redux it was working file with single reducer but when I used combined reducers it's stops rendering but still able to log all data in console, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I have been facing this issue for days.

I have tried:

- reinstalling expo
- upgrading expo
- recreating new project
  I have searched the internet but I have been unable to find any solution

**Reducer**

```js
import {
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
  PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL,
} from "../../../constants";

const initialState = [];

const productDetailsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
case PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST:
  return { loading: true };
case PRODUCT_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
  return { loading: false, product: action.payload };
case PRODUCT_DETAILS_FAIL:
  return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
default:
  return state;
  }
};

export default productDetailsReducer;
```

**component**

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, ScrollView, Linking, Text, View, Image } from "react-native";
import { Card, Button } from "react-native-elements";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'

import { getProduct } from '../Redux/actions/products.Action.js'

export const Product = ({ route }) => {
    const { itemId } = route.params;
    // 376
    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const storeState = useSelector((state) => state.productDetailsReducer);
    const {product, loading, error} = storeState;


    const printdata = () => {
        console.log(product.name);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getProduct(itemId));
    }, [dispatch]);


    return (
        <>
            <Text> {loading ? "loading" : product.name}</Text>
            <Button onPress={() => { printdata() }}>press</Button>
        </>
    )
}
export default Product
```

**error**
[image]

**state**
[image]

Comment: What is the state in the selector? Can you see what actions are dispatched and with what data (log in the reducer)?

Comment: If you're worried that `printData` logs the data but that `Products` is not rendering your data then maybe this is because you are not rendering `products` in your component.

Comment: i was rendering before but this crashers the app so I remove that from view to check weather data is coming or not

Comment: So you have code that crashes your app and want to know why but you didn't include that code in your question. I hope you can see the problem there. When an app crashes you usually get an error, maybe include that in your question as well.

Comment: i edited the question and added the code which cause the error

Comment: You can't use `product.name` if loading or error is true because I think  product is null or undefined so you are trying to do `undefined.name` or `null.name`. You still didn't mention **what the error is** nor **what code causes the error**

Comment: yes i added error screenshots

Comment: Your product is undefined but loading is false, maybe you had an error? I hate repeating myself but **What is the state in the selector?** You can log it with:  `const storeState = useSelector((state) => console.log('state is:',JSON.stringify(state,undefined,2)) || state.productDetailsReducer);`

Comment: same as before it logs the data on console but did not render

Comment: I don't see the error in the console of the last image, are you sure that is the last time it logs state before the error?

Comment: yes i can see data logged in console , once i removed the `product.name ` from render, if it stays there app will  crashes once i removed it , then i can call prinfData funtion to logged the data to console , and it logged the desired result

Comment: you can see the error on display because error was beneath the logged state but you can see the error on error image in question

Comment: thank you @HMR  for helping me

Answer (score 1):

change

```
const initialState = [] to  const initialState = {}

const printdata = () => {
    console.log(product?.name); // check is product exists then console.log(product.name)
}
```

Comment: thank you very much you do not know how  i'm struggling with this error for past 5 days it's working now . But without `?`   printsData function  logged the data   to console , but  without `?` it does not render now i put the `?` in `<Text>{product?.name}</Text>` it's working , thanks again